# Appcelerator TextField looses focus in TableView on Android 5.0.2

Tags: android, tableview, appcelerator, textfield, titanium-alloy

I've just had a customer deliver me a test phone to deploy my app on. This is a ZTE R84 which runs Google Android v5.0.2. Only on this device and OS I am experiencing an issue with TextFields in Tableviews.

Basically when I have the Keyboard type set to DEFAULT and try to edit the text in the field on this device, the field loses focus immediately. If I set the keyboard type to Titanium.UI.KEYBOARD_TYPE_NUMBER_PAD, it works as expected.

If I take the field outside of the TableView, then I have no problem whatsoever.

Open to suggestions about how I fix this one, other than sending the phone back to my customer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can get rid of this issue by setting **[windowSoftInputMode](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Window-property-windowSoftInputMode)** property of that window which contains the tableview to **[Ti.UI.Android.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Android-property-SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN)**

```
"Window" : {
    windowSoftInputMode : Ti.UI.Android.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN
}
```